# PHP - How can i make php to show webservers 404 error page on header 404?

Tags: php, html, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I am using PHP for scripting, and sometimes I need to throw a "404 Not Found" status message. I have tried this:

```
<?php
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']." 404 Not Found");
header("Location: 404.html");
exit();
?>
```

But it's redirecting the user to the `404.html` page and I don't think it's good practice to do so. Instead, I would like to keep the user on the same page which he accessed, throw a 404 status code and show the 404.html contents.

I have also tried setting the error page in my rewrite rules, and it's working correctly. But I want PHP to show the 404 file's content along with a 404 status code.

I have also tried doing:

```
<?php
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']." 404 Not Found");
exit();
```

But this gives only a 404 status code and a blank page. I would like to get the contents of a 404.html or 404.php file.

Comment: You can `require()` a 404.php file below `header()`.

Comment: The Location directive requests a redirection to the browser...
Use http_response_code() to set the http status code and does not redirect to that page but include it with require or include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `include` to include the file with the 404 error message in it and set the header to 404.
Please make sure you send the header before outputting anything else.

```
<?php
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
include("404.html");
exit(); // terminate the script
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_get_contents`:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].file_get_content("404.html"));
exit();
```

Or just use echo:

```
echo file_get_content("404.html");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It's a better way do it with apache `.htaccess` file.

In `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /not_found.html
```